ChromeOS のコンテナ環境で apt update を実行するとGPG error などが表示される
実行環境

OS: ChromeOS
croshを使用

期待値
apt updateを実行した際に、GPGやリポジトリに関するエラーが表示されずに正常に動作させたい。
下記は表示されたエラー。
W: GPG error: https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/128 bookworm Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4EB27DB2A3B88B8B NO_PUBKEY E88979FB9B30ACF2 NO_PUBKEY 32EE5355A6BC6E42
E: The repository 'https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/128 bookworm Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.

再現手順

CTRL+ALT+Tを押して Chrome シェル (crosh) に入り、デフォルトのterminaVM を入力する。

vmc start termina


デフォルトのpenguinコンテナの名前を変更する。

lxc stop penguin --force
lxc rename penguin debian


ubuntuという名前の新しい Ubuntu コンテナを作成する。

lxc remote set-url images https://images.lxd.canonical.com/
lxc launch ubuntu:24.04 ubuntu


新しいコンテナに入る。自動的にrootになる。

lxc start ubuntu
lxc exec ubuntu -- bash


デフォルトのUbuntuユーザーのグループ メンバーシップを取得し、ユーザーを削除する。

groups ubuntu >update-groups
sed -i 'y/ /,/; s/ubuntu,:,ubuntu,/sudo usermod -aG /; s/$/ \$USER/' update-groups
killall -u ubuntu
userdel -r ubuntu
sed -i '/^ubuntu/d' /etc/sudoers.d/90-cloud-init-users


配布が最新であることを確認する。
Google の Crostini 固有のパッケージをインストールする準備として、まず Ubuntu を最新の状態にする。

apt update
apt upgrade


Crostini サポート パッケージを手動でインストールする。

echo "deb https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages bookworm main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cros.list
if [ -f /dev/.cros_milestone ]; then sudo sed -i "s?packages?packages/$(cat /dev/.cros_milestone)?" /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cros.list; fi
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
apt update

参考リンク
https://www.reddit.com/r/Crostini/wiki/howto/run-ubuntu/?rdt=42779#wiki_workaround_for_chrome_os_m107.2B_.28cros-ui-config_0.15_all.deb.29


についてですが、まずは公開鍵をファイルに保存し、リポジトリ設定に追加します。

wget -O - https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/128/dists/bookworm/Release.gpg | gpg --dearmor > /usr/share/keyrings/cros-packages-archive-keyring.gpg

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/Ubuntu.sourceに
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cros-packages-archive-keyring.gpg] https://storage.googleapis.com/cros-packages/128 bookworm main を追記します。
cd /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
nano ubuntu.source

最後にapt updateをすればエラーが表示されずに正常に動作するはずです。
